# Forward to another controller/action from module

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to figure out the best way to forward to another controller/action when the MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR is triggered.

What I have so far in the bootstrap of module is:

```
$eventManager = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager();
$eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, function($e) {
$routeMatch = new Router\RouteMatch(array('controller'=>'my-controller','action'=>'my-action');
}, 100);
```

My questions are:

1. How do I dispatch $routeMatch?
2. Is this the right way to go about this?

For background, I am upgrading an old ZF1 application where I used frontend plugin to do this. This is a cms application that when no matching routes are found then a cms controller is used to match route with db entry and return page.

Thanks

Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to re-dispatch the event with your new route.

After you have created your new route match add this:

```
$newEvent = clone $e;
$e->stopPropagation(TRUE);
$newEvent->setRouteMatch($routeMatch);
$eventManager->trigger('dispatch', $newEvent);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a different problem now :) But this works :)

Comment: Do you mind looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32430595/router-match-not-returning-matchedroutename which is my new issue.. Very much related to this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I do it when a user wants to access an action not allowed for its role. Using your $e from params:

```
$match = $e->getRouteMatch();
$match->setParam('controller', 'User\Controller\Account');
$match->setParam('action', 'denied');
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer Conti. Essentially you are doing the same as I am. However, because I am doing this within the dispatch_error event simply setting the routematch is not enough as the "dispatching" has essentially happened and determined there is no matching route. Hence, why I am resetting the Route... I just dont know how to re-dispatch.

Comment: I am glad the other solution fixed your issue, I am considering to test it within my app too although mine code works :).